# No Assertions Ran with night watch js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

Hi everyone I am teaching myself night watch js. I am trying to use the page object model and I am having a bit of an issue. Basically whenever I execute my code I see the message "No assertions ran" in the console. Can someone care to explain?

The URL I am testing is: https://www.nypl.org/

Here is **/pages/homepage.js**

```
     var elements = {
         searchbutton: '.nyplHomepageApp button[name = "Search Button"]',
         Authortalksconversations: '.titleTabs #tab-0',
         Exibitions: '.titleTabs #tab-1',
         Performing_AF: '.titleTabs #tab-2',
         Other_Events: '.titleTabs #tab-3',
         DonateButton: '#donateButton',
         Shop: '#shopTopLink',
         loadicon: '.dcom-loader',

 };

 var quicksearch = {
         go: function() {
                 return this
                         .waitForElementVisible('body', 6000)
                         .assert.visible('.nyplHomepageApp button[name = "Search Button"]')
                         .api.pause(4000)
                         .click('.nyplHomepageApp button[name = "Search Button"]')
                         .setValue('.desktopSearch-form-inputBox #desktopSearch-form-searchInput', 'history')
                         .pause(4000)
                         .click('button[type="submit"]')
                         .pause(4000)

                 end();
         }

 };

 module.exports = {

         elements,

         commands: [
                 quicksearch,
         ]

 };
```

And here is tests/homepagetest.js

```
     module.exports = {

'Q': function(browser) {
    var goto = browser.page.homepage();
    goto.go;


    //browser.end();
        }

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, `quicksearch` isn't a function it's an object. You could change it to

```
var quicksearch = function() {
  //do stuff
}
```

Or you need to just call `goto.go()`

You also have an error in your test on the first pause. Change it to this and it will start working...

```
return this
        .waitForElementVisible('body', 6000)
        .assert.visible('.nyplHomepageApp button[name = "Search Button"]')
        .api.pause(4000) //this is the change you need to make it work
        .click('.nyplHomepageApp button[name = "Search Button"]')
        .setValue('.desktopSearch-form-inputBox #desktopSearch-form-searchInput', 'history')
        .pause(4000)
        .click('button[type="submit"]')
        .pause(4000)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried the latter "call goto.quicksearch.go" and I got an error message " ✖ TypeError: Cannot read property 'go' of undefined"

Comment: That means that `quicksearch` is undefined for some reason. Try logging `goto.quicksearch` to see what you get.

Comment: I see what it is, you just need to call `goto.go()`. Although, it looks like there may be some errors in your test but I at least got it to run that way. I updated my post with the change you need to get the test running.

Comment: I am really baffle by the fact I am unable to get this to work. I changed my code to reflect yours and I still get the message "no assertions ran" .

Comment: I'm not sure either. I copied your code from above and got it working with very little modification. All I did was change the `.pause()` to `.api.pause()`. And I changed `goto.quicksearch` to `goto.go()` and it started working.

Comment: whoops, I figured out what was going wrong. basically this was frustrating me so much I deleted the entire project and started from scratch. I was missing ' "page_objects_path": "./pages/"' in the nightwatch.json .